# Using Squid on Debian, Cannot Connect Error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, squid

I am trying to set up Squid on Debian and am getting a connection refused error:

```
squidclient http://www.apple.com/ > test
client: ERROR: Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1:3128: Connection refused
```

Here is my config:

```
visible_hostname none

cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy

cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 2048 16 256
cache_mem 512 MB

cache_access_log /var/log/squid/access.log

emulate_httpd_log on

strip_query_terms off
read_ahead_gap 128 Kb

collapsed_forwarding on
refresh_stale_hit 30 seconds

retry_on_error on

maximum_object_size_in_memory 1 MB

acl all src 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
acl purgehosts src 127.0.0.1/255.255.255.255

# Caching static objects in __data is important.
# Without that, apache processes sit around spooling static objects.
acl QUERY urlpath_regex /cgi-bin/ /_edit /_admin /_login /_nocache /_recache /__lib /__fudge
acl PURGE method PURGE
acl POST method POST

cache deny QUERY
cache deny POST

http_access allow PURGE purgehosts
http_access deny PURGE
http_access allow all

http_port 127.0.0.1:80
http_port 50.56.206.139:80
cache_peer 127.0.0.1 parent 80 0 originserver no-query no-digest default

redirect_rewrites_host_header off

read_ahead_gap 128 Kb

shutdown_lifetime 5 seconds
```

Any ideas why this is happening?  What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `http_port 127.0.0.1:3128` in your configuration.

Edit: It looks like you want reverse proxy/http accelerator configuration. In that case do not test squid with `squidclient http://www.apple.com/` -- try to access your web page with normal browser or use tool like wget.

See http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy for some information.

I have no experience with this mode in squid but delete http_port other than `http_port 50.56.206.139:80 accel defaultsite=your.main.website` and try again.

Comment: I am new to Squid and was using a config file from a server at work, so I wasn't sure what options I needed. I just want the easiest Squid setup possible.

Comment: What mode of squid operation do you want: web cache, transparent web cache, or maybe reverse proxy in front of apache?

Comment: Ok, I changed the port to 3128 and now trying "squidclient http://www.apple.com/ > test" works.  What other things have I done wrong? I feel like I don't know what all these options mean.

Comment: I am using apache, and I just want Squid to cache my pages for performance reasons.

Comment: Ok, that works. Looking at the HTTP headers and don't see anything about Squid...

Comment: What's in /var/log/squid/access.log? The apache is bound to what ip/port? It can be 80 as long as it's limited to 127.0.0.1 - use `BindAddress 127.0.0.1` in it's config file.

Comment: Use BindAddress 127.0.0.1 in my apache config? That gives me errors when restarting it.  There is nothing in the Squid log.

Comment: No entries in your squid log means you are connecting directly to apache, most probably due to apache listens on port 80 on all addresses. You have to configure it properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3074/discussion-between-kupson-and-zed-said)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out for squid configuration:

http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-to-install-squid-proxy-on-centos-6/